# Failed to add ContentType using SPMeta2 opensource library

Tags: content-type, csom

This is my code Please help ( I am also creating contentType,siteColumn,views For library, creating  fields for contentType,every thing is going correct except ContentType is attaching with list.

```
public static WebModelNode DeployLists()
{
    return SPMeta2Model.NewWebModel(web => {web.AddList(ListDefinitions.TrackingRegister, list => {     list.AddField(SiteColumns.YMAInvestigation).AddField(SiteColumns.YMContactEmail).AddField(SiteColumns.YMProductionLocation).AddContentTypeLink(ContentTypes.ClaimTrackingContentType).AddListView(Views.TRView); }); });
}
```

Comment: where is the code ?? :)

Comment: public static WebModelNode DeployLists() {
 return SPMeta2Model.NewWebModel(web =>
 { web.AddList(ListDefinitions.TrackingRegister, list =>
  {  list
  .AddField(SiteColumns.YMAInvestigation)
  .AddField(SiteColumns.YMContactEmail)  .AddField(SiteColumns.YMProductionLocation)
.AddContentTypeLink(ContentTypes.ClaimTrackingContentType)
  .AddListView(Views.TRView);
   });
   });
 }

Comment: M.Qassas , please see my above comment